# Condition for sequential convergence implies convergence in whole.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be defined as $f(3\cdot2^k)=1$, for $k\in\mathbb N$, and $f=0$ otherwise.
Let $a_n=2^n$, for any $s\in [0,\infty)$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n+s)=0$, since $\{a_n+s\}$ and $\{3\cdot2^k\}$ only have finite common elements. But $f(x)$ has no limit as $x\to \infty$.

My question is that if there is some additional property (such as continuous) added to $f$ to guarantee that if there is a sequence $a_n\uparrow\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$ exists and $\forall s\in [0,\infty)$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n+s)$, then we have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$$

Comment: $f(1/|x|) {}{}{}{}$

Comment: Continuity is not enough. You can slightly modify your $f$ to being continuous: just make it affine on the intervals $[3\cdot2^k-1, 3\cdot2^k]$ and $[3\cdot2^k,3\cdot2^k+1]$. Imho your argument can be modified to draw the same conclusion.

Comment: @gerw Yes. Thanks!